# Google Places API: place_changed not fired

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I have a problem including the Google Places API. I've set up everything with API key, the listing / suggestion works good but the `place_changed` event do not get fired when i select an suggestion.

Check the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xj2d77be/3/

It should work, but i have absolutely no idea why it does not.

**code snippet (from posted fiddle):**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('mapLocation'));
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    console.log(place);
  });
  console.log("Initialized")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<input type="text" id="mapLocation" />
```

Answer (score 2):

try this, this will work i have updated your code,

https://jsfiddle.net/xj2d77be/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#mapLocation")[0]);
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            console.log(place);
        });
    console.log("Initialized")
});
```

using SearchBox:

https://jsfiddle.net/xj2d77be/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('mapLocation'));
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
            var place = searchBox.getPlaces();
            console.log(place);
        });
    console.log("Initialized")
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But i have no idea why "SearchBox" do not work. I found a sample from Google where thes uses SearchBox, too – with "places_change" state.

Comment: @KevinLieser follow this link, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

Comment: Thats the page i am talking about: As you see, they init `var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);`

Comment: @kevinLieser please check my answer, i have updated example using searchbox

Answer (score 0):

There is no "place_changed" event or `.getPlace()` function for SearchBox. It should be "places_changed" and `.getPlaces()`.

[Documentation:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#SearchBox)

> **Methods**
>
> **getPlaces()** Return Value:  Array
>
> Returns the query selected by the user, or null if no places have been found yet, to be used with places_changed event.
>
> **Events**
>
> **places_changed** Arguments:  None
>
> This event is fired when the user selects a query, getPlaces should be used to get new places.

**Note:** the `.getPlaces()` function returns an array rather than a single place.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('mapLocation'));
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'places_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlaces();
    console.log(place);
  });
  console.log("Initialized")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<input type="text" id="mapLocation" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the `place_changed` event would fire until I refreshed the page, then it would not fire anymore (using Google Chrome on a local webpage).  You have to restart Chrome or close the developer tools and refresh the page for the event to fire again.