# places_changed is not triggering

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to get the first place that we get by getPlaces function. However, my places_changed is not triggering for some reason.

Note: Locations contain the name of locations like London, Manchester etc.

This is my code

```
for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    // Create a new input element
    console.log({i})
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.id = "location"+i;
    input.value = locations[i]; // Set the initial value
    
    // Create a SearchBox associated with the input element
    let searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    console.log({searchBox})
    
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', () => {
      console.log('here')
      const places = searchBox.getPlaces();
      if (places.length != 0) {
        console.log('places', places, places[0])
      }
    })
}
```

I have also tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40177088/google-places-api-place-changed-not-fired) solutions, but it is still not triggering.

Answer (score 0):

places_changed event is triggered when the user selects a prediction from the list. you programmatically sets the value of the input element, but that won't trigger the places_changed event.

```
const mapDiv = document.createElement('div');
const placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(mapDiv);
```

findPlaceFromQuery to get place details

```
for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    const query = locations[i];

    placesService.findPlaceFromQuery({
        query: query,
        fields: ['name', 'geometry', 'place_id', 'formatted_address'] // Add or remove fields as needed
    }, (results, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK && results && results.length) {
            const place = results[0];
            console.log('Place details:', place);
        }
    });
}
```